# Site Collection Reader

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, permissions, site-collection

It's straightforward to add a user with Site Collection Administrator access.  But how can I easily add a user to a site collection with only read access to the site collection?

Answer (score 0):

In site collection settings > permission, from here click on visitor group...add the user here and it will get read access to entire site collection.

Or create a new group and assign custom permission to it ( read permissions) then add users in that group